# can't start MacVim in Tmux terminal

Tags: vim, macvim, tmux

I'm playing around with Tmux. I don't know why but I don't seem able to start MacVim in a Tmux terminal. When type mvim inside the terminal window, MacVim start in its own window outside the terminal.

I can start Vim in the Tmux terminal window, when I type vi in the terminal window, Vim starts up in the terminal.

But I rather use MacVim

Anyone else experienced the issue that MacVim doesn't start in the terminal window? How did you solve it.

Thanks for your help,

Anthony

Answer (score 2):

That's the default behavior. The command for using MacVim's CLI executable is:

```
$ mvim -v filename
```

See `$ vim --help` for all the available flags.

Comment: thanks romaini. I know see, that MacVim does start in the terminal, but I lost my solarized colorscheme. I guess this has to do something with Mac OSX. I believe I should download iTerm2, right?

Comment: You need to change your terminal emulator's color palette to match solarized. I think there's a download on the solarized landing page. But if I were you I wouldn't bother: that colorscheme is a crappy and fragile hack.

Comment: Could you help me understand the motivation to use `mvim`/`gvim` CLI? Is `mvim -v` different from `vim` in any tangible way? (assuming you have updated both to latest version)

Comment: @scicalculator, the default `/usr/bin/vim` used to be a very small build with very few useful features. It used to be built without Ruuby/Python support and without clipboard support. Apple introduced `+python/dyn` and `+ruby/dyn` in Lion or mountain Lion but it still doesn't have clipboard support and that's IMO a *very* compelling reason to use another Vim. MacVim is simply the most convenient way to get a proper Vim on Mac OS X. `mvim` is a wrapper that launches a GUI MacVim instance by default or MacVim's bundled CLI executable if you add the `-v` flag.

Comment: @scicalculator, but in usage, the only noticeable difference between running `mvim -v` and running `vim` is clipboard support.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I always kept my vim install up to date (huge-install), so I can now see why this would be convenient alternative. That being said, does `mvim -v` copy-paste directly link to `pbcopy`/`pbpaste`? In this case, would you need to run it through `reattach-to-user-namespace` in `tmux`?

Comment: @scicalculator, honestly I don't know for sure if it uses `pbcopy`/`pbpaste` under the hood but yes, adding `set-option -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l bash"` to your `~/.tmux.conf` is a necessary (but quick, easy and painless) hack.